# Relationship between hyperalgebra (algebra of distributions) of an affine group scheme to its cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, affine-geometry, group-schemes

Let $G$ be an affine group scheme, and $\mathrm{Dist}(G)$ its hyperalgebra.

I am wondering what is the relationship between $\mathrm{Dist}$(G) and $G$ interms of Cohomology?

Is there a cohomology theory for $\mathrm{Dist}(G)$, if so what information does it give?

Comment: Do you have Jantzens book "Representations of Algebraic Groups"?  Chapter I.7 is all about $\mathrm{Dist}(G)$.

Comment: I do (infact I just started reading I.7 tonight) though I was especially wondering \textit{(a priori)} since $Dist(G)=Lie(G)$ in the case of a field of characteristic 0.  
Then, is there an explicit relationship between the lia lagebra cohomology of Lie(G) and the rational cohomology of G.